# Mongodb Aggregate: Combine multiple keys into an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to combine three keys in my documents to an array using mongodb aggregate. 
Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

Input Document:

```
{  
    _id: "xyz", 
    p1: "A", 
    p2: "E", 
    p3: "C"
}
```

Output Document:

```
{ 
   _id: "xyz",
   p: ["A", "E", "C"] 
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this using mongodb aggregate?

Cheers 
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aggregation's [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) stage, You can do as like below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: { p: [ "$p1", "$p2", "$p3" ] }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7n20pPFWLMw)